# google map local search, how to search address, local from a specific country only?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-local-search, google-ajax-search-api

I am using Google map local search API and I'm trying to search and get result from a specific country only. Wonder If anyone have experience about this.

Comment: The Google Maps API and the Google Search API are different APIs. I'd suggest that the tag of "google-maps" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Google blog post](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2009/10/web-search-in-your-country.html) explains how to do it. Hope this helps!